# Is it known why Jackie Lane who played the character of Dodo Chaplet left Doctor Who so abruptly?

Tags: doctor-who, behind-the-scenes

The character of Dodo Chaplet (sadly, Jackie Lane the actress who played the character died recently) had a rather unusually short period, from February to July 1966 alongside William Hartnell as the Doctor.

Besides the short period, the manner in which she left was also unusual: Halfway through her last adventure (the War Machines), she abruptly departs for a rest in the country after being hypnotised, and never reappears. At the end of the story this was explained by the Doctor that she had decided to remain in the 20th century.

It was well known that Hartnell could, at times, be difficult to work with. Was this the reason Jackie Lane left? Or was it something else like feeling she was bored with the part?

Comment: Her [bio on the Doctor Who Wiki](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Jackie_Lane) indicates that a) her contract had expired and b) that she never acted again, which suggests that she wasn't seen as a bankable asset

Comment: I can only think of two companions who didn't get an on-air departure - Dodo and Liz Shaw. Any others?

Comment: On the opposite track (somewhat fitting for a programme on time travel) , Mel Bush is, I believe, the only companion who didn't have an on screen introductory story, joining the sixth Doctor in the serial Terror of the Vervoids, when, she and the Sixth Doctor have been travelling together for some time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[According](https://drwhointerviews.wordpress.com/2009/10/03/jackie-lane-1988/) to Jackie Lane (the actress who played her), the character didn't fit into future plans for the series and was written out by Innes Lloyd:

> I think (Innes Lloyd) had definite plans for the series which neither Steven nor Dodo really fitted, and half way through my first year I was told that Dodo was to be written out. I would have liked a dramatic ending and my farewell just two episodes into ‘The War Machines’, and not even on camera but in reported speech, was a bit of an anti-climax.

FWIW in the same interview she states that she got on well with William Hartnell.